# Java: Comparing hashsets as efficently as possible

Tags: java, performance, hashset

I have 3 hashsets. goodLinkSet, badLinkSet and testLinkSet.

goodLinkSet holds a list of URLs that work and badLinkSet holds a list of URLs that don't work. testLinkSet holds a list of URLs that I need to check if they are good are bad, some of the links in here have been tested already in the other two sets.

What I want to do is remove all the strings/links in testLinkSet that appear in goodLinkSet and badLinkSet so I'm not testing URLs multiple times. I want to do this as efficiently and as fast as possible. A for each loop seems to be a bit slow.

What's the most efficient way of running this? Are there any functions that does this for me? Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: All you need is at most two `contains` calls per entry. `contains` is O(1). What's bugging you? Do you already have a performance issue, or you're just asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to do is remove all the strings/links in testLinkSet that appear in goodLinkSet and badLinkSet so I'm not testing URLs multiple times.

The most efficient way is to not remove the entries but to test them as you need to.

```
for(URL url: testLinkSet) {
    if(goodLinkSet.conatins(url) || badListSet.conatins(url)) continue;

    // test url
}
```

This does far less work as it does the same amount of tests, but avoid modifying anything.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense and I should have thought of that. The only question I have is seeing as you're checking two sets for each link will it slow down much as it has to access both? I imagine it will only take milliseconds?

Comment: It should take of the order of 100 ns each, not milli-seconds.

Answer (score 6):

> What I want to do is remove all the strings/links in testLinkSet that appear in goodLinkSet and badLinkSet so I'm not testing URLs multiple times.

```
testLinkSet.removeAll(goodLinkSet);
testLinkSet.removeAll(badLinkSet);
```

This will run a loop internally, but unless you have (many) millions of links you won't have time to count to 1 before it completes.

If you need better performance, you should track each individual link and remove/add them as and when they get tested.

Comment: A little bit of saving can be had with a manual loop that checks each member against the second set only if the check against the first one failed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check at insertion time:

```
boolean addToTestLinkSet(String str) {
  if (goodLinkSet.contains(str) || badLinkSet.contains(str))
    return false;
  testLinkSet.add(str);
  return true;
}
```

`contains()` on `HashSet`s is O(1), so the overhead should be pretty low.

The solution is pretty similar to Peter's but has the added bonus of using less memory (because it will avoid temporarily storing useless entries in `testLinkSet`).

Additionally, if you know that `badLinkSet.size() > goodLinkSet.size()`, you may even swap the order in which the two sets are tested.